# JS: Regex - replace parts of domains in full text

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url, subdomain

I'm confronted with a problem. I have a whole html page stored in one variable and I would like to change certain URLs that meets criteria.

We are looking only for certain top level domain, let's say ".XYZ" and if we find it we would like the ending to be ".XYZ.ABC" - just adding ".ABC".

For example `<a href="http://example.xyz/">link</a>` would be changed to `<a href="http://example.xyz.abc/">link</a>`

But if domain already has ".abc" ending we should leave it alone.
I would like to change text of all links, so src, href and also js values like `var link="123.xyz/1.bmp";`

Other examples

```
www.123.xyz -> www.123.xyz.abc
abc.xyz/1.bmp -> abc.xyz.abc/1.bmp
eee.xyz.abc -> eee.xyz.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
text.replace(/\.xyz(?!\.abc)/g, ".xyz.abc")
```

Comment: It should work only for links... maybe there should be a criteria that if this link is located in " " or ' ' only then it could change a text.
So, critera is: link which is located in " " or ' ' and doesn't have spaces inside, check for last characters before / to be .xyz or in case there is double // (eg. http://123.xyz/) then search for text before third / (if there is /) and text doesn't end there, in that case check only if there is .xyz at the end. If this critera is meet then change .xyz to .xyz.abc

The code above fails if link is 1.xyz.com/. We should only look for .xyz ending.